# Quickbooks Webconnector (with DevKit) "A query request did not find a matching object in QuickBooks"

Tags: php, quickbooks, devkit

I am using the Consolibyte's "DevKit" (example_web_connector.php) to try and integrate with the Quickbooks WebConnector.

I'm getting this annoying error for the `ItemInventoryQueryRq`.

A query request did not find a matching object in QuickBooks

I am told that the error means there are no records for the WebConnector to retrieve, but I am looking at the Items in Quickbooks and there are plenty of them there. I am using the simplest possible Request XML with no filters so I would have thought it should get all of them.

Here is the request XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="8.0" ?>
 <QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
   <ItemInventoryQueryRq>
   </ItemInventoryQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
 </QBXML>
```

The sequence of SOAP requests is

1. Incoming: serverVersion
2. Outgoing: serverVersionResponse
3. Incoming: clientVersion
4. Outgoing: clientVersionResponse
5. Incoming: authenticate  (At this point I "Enqueue" the product request)
6. Outgoing: authenticateResponse
7. Incoming: sendRequestXML (Includes a load of Quickbooks "company" data)
8. Outgoing: ItemInventoryQueryRq
9. Incoming: ItemInventoryQueryRs (Contains status message: "A query request did not find a matching object in QuickBooks")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A query request did not find a matching object in QuickBooks

This means exactly what it says - that you searched for something, and nothing matched your search.

> I am told that the error means there are no records for the WebConnector to retrieve, but I am looking at the Items in Quickbooks and there are plenty of them there.

Then there are one of two things wrong here. Either:

a) You have a horribly corrupted QuickBooks company file (unlikely)

OR

b) You're either not looking at, or not querying for, the correct items

Are you *100% positive* that you're looking at *inventory* items in QuickBooks, and not some other type of item (service, assembly, discount, sales tax, non-inventory, etc.)?

Are you *100% positive* that that's the query you sent to QuickBooks?

I would bet lots of good $$$ that you're not looking at the correct item types or are sending a different query to QuickBooks...

Comment: Yes I see now I should have been using ItemQueryRq... Thanks!